# parsing the text in python of the given format

Tags: python-3.x

I want to parse a file which looks like this:

`<item> <one-of> <item> deepa vats </item> <item> deepa <ruleref uri="#Dg-e_n_t41"/> </item> </one-of> <tag> out = "u-dvats"; </tag> </item>
<item> <one-of> <item> maitha al owais </item> <item> doctor maitha </item> <item> maitha <ruleref uri="#Dg-clinical_nutrition24"/> </item> </one-of> <tag> out = "u-mal_owais"; </tag> </item>`

The result should be username:out for example:

```
deepa vats : u-dvats and maitha al owais : u-mal_owais
```

to extract the username i tried

```
print ([j for i,j in re.findall(r"(<item>)\s*(.*?)\s*(?!\1)(?:</item>)",line)])
if len(list1) != 0:
    print(list1[0].split("<item>")[-1])
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Suggested reading: [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the xml with `objectify` from [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

To parse an XML string you could use `objectify.fromstring()`. Then you can use dot notation or square bracket notation to navigate through the element and use the `text` property to get the text inside the element. Like so:

```
item = objectify.fromstring(item_str)
item_text = item.itemchild['anotherchild'].otherchild.text
```

From there you can manipulate the string and format it.

In this case I can see that you want the text inside `item >> one-of >> item` and the text inside `item >> tag`. In order to get it we could do something like this:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> item_str = '<item> <one-of> <item> maitha al owais </item> <item> doctor maitha </item> <item> maitha <ruleref uri="#Dg-clinical_nutrition24"/> </item> </one-of> <tag> out = "u-mal_owais"; </tag> </item>'
>>> item = objectify.fromstring(item_str)
>>> item_text = item['one-of'].item.text
>>> tag_text = item['tag'].text
>>> item_text
' maitha al owais '
>>> tag_text
' out = "u-mal_owais"; '
```

Since python doesn't allow hyphens in variable names and since `tag` is a property of the objectify object you have to use bracket notation instead of dot notation in this case.

Comment: hi, i have few lines like this <item> avish hodarkar <tag> out = "u-ahodarkar"; </tag> </item>, where the one-of tag is not there. how to check this one out.

Comment: You could use a try/except or check `item.__dict__` to see if the child element exists like: `if 'one-of' in item.__dict__:  # get child content`

Comment: Hey hi, How do i extract the all the usernames present in between <one-of>

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using BeautifulSoup:

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(your_text, "lxml")
' '.join(x.strip() for x in soup.strings if x.strip())
#'deepa vats deepa out = "u-dvats"; maitha al owais doctor maitha maitha out = "u-mal_owais";'
```